# not being able to initialize REST object in discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, discord, discord.js

I am currently trying to make a simple discord bot following the discord.js documentation.(https://discordjs.guide/creating-your-bot/creating-commands.html#command-deployment-script)
My issue is regarding the deploy-command.js file:

```
const {SlashCommandBuilder} = require('@discordjs/builders')
const {Routes} = require('discord-api-types/v9')
const dotenv = require('dotenv')
const {REST} = require("@discordjs/rest");

dotenv.config()
const token = process.env.DISCORD_JS_TOKEN
const clientId = process.env.clientId
const guildId = process.env.guildId

const commands = [
    new SlashCommandBuilder().setName('ping').setDescription('Replies with pong!'),
    new SlashCommandBuilder().setName('server').setDescription('Replies with server info!'),
    new SlashCommandBuilder().setName('user').setDescription('Replies with user info!')
].map(command => command.toJSON())

const rest = new REST({version:'9'}).setToken(token)

rest.put(Routes.applicationGuildCommands(clientId,guildId),{body:commands})
    .then(() => console.log("Successfully registered application commands from file"))
    .catch(() => console.log('error happened'))
```

I'm getting an error at the following line:

const rest = new REST({version:'9'}).setToken(token) ---> Interface cannot be instantiated

I've tried removing package-lock.json and node_modules and then reinstalling them via "npm install", that didn't have any effect.
There is a REST interface and a REST class in the discordjs/rest module. While hovering over the
{version:'9'}, I'm getting the following message: "Invalid number of arguments, expected 0" and the suggestion to "create constructor in class rest"(which there already is one, for the REST class)

This issue has been extremly frustrating as I can't seem to find anyone else that had a similar issue and all the videos I've watched on youtube execute the exact same code with no issues(only difference being that they use visual studio code in the videos).

Any help would be appreciated.

software used:

nodejs(tried version 16.6.0 and 17.0.0)

webstorm 2021.2.2

Comment: Is your token correct?

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow. I would recommend using vscode for discord.js development as is has some really good language features but WebStorm is good too. It could be possible that your syntax is incorrect. Make sure that you have spaces between the curly brackets : ```const rest = new REST({ version: '9' }).setToken(token);```

Answer (score 0):

Ive came across the same issue. For anyone whos coming across this thread and has the same issue, i found out that i was using the wrong Client ID. i was using my personal Client ID instead of the ClientID of the Bot found in the discord developer portal.

The documentation doesn't clearly state this annoyingly

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31079195)

Comment: @Terry how do you mean it doesn’t really answer the question? It’s the solution to the askers problem?